# Removing lagging and trailing zeros in an audio recording

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure, matlab-deployment

I was posed a question to make an audio recording of the word sad;
a. remove the dc content and normalize the recordings
b. remove the lagging and trailing zeros in the sample i recorded.

These are my two queries?
1. Does removing the lagging mean, removing the zeros from within the audio recording
2, Is removing the trailing zeros implemented by this method

```
  new_signal_sad(52000:end)=[];
```

Why i am so uncertain is that when i play the sad recording using:

```
   sound(sad, 44100);
```

it plays perfectly well.

when i play the sound recording after removing the lagging and trailing zeros using this:

```
 sound(new_signal_sad, 44100);
```

all i hear is a brief 'shhhhhhh' then sad, though it's much quicker than the first.

This is the code for my program!!!

```
%Removing dc offset from sad signal
ip1=wavread('N:\Arutu Peter\sad.wav');
for channelNo = 1:size(ip1,2)
ip1(:, channelNo) = ip1(:, channelNo) - mean(ip1(:, channelNo));
end
%Normalizing the sad signal
sad=ip1/max(ip1);

%Now to remove trailing zeros and lagging from sad
frame_duration=0.1;
frame_len=fs*frame_duration;
N=length(sad);
num_frames=floor(N/frame_len);
new_signal_sad=zeros(N,1);
count=0;

%step1: Break the sound signal into frames
for k=1:num_frames
frame=sad( (k-1)*frame_len+1 :frame_len*k);
%step 2: Identifying the silent frames with maximum amplitude less than 0.02
max_val=max(frame);
if (max_val>0.02)
    %signal with no zeros
    count=count+1; 
    %step3: construct a new signal with no zeros
    new_signal_sad( (count-1)*frame_len+1:frame_len*count)=frame;
    %%Removing trailing zeros from the new_signal love
    new_signal_sad(52000:end)=[];
    subplot(4,2,1);
    plot(new_signal_sad);
    grid;
    title('sad');

 end

end
```

Comment: You are not actually "removing" the frames from the new signal - you just don't set them to anything other than zero. Also, you should have some condition in your loop that prevents it from removing a frame if you're already passed where your code has determined the start of the sound is - otherwise you might spuriously set frames you want to keep to zero.

Comment: Please kindly show me this in code, the syntax and the functions in matlab are all new to me. Perhaps with a simple illustration...